# Is there a simpler way to filter out Counter keys by length? python

Tags: python, collections, counter

Is there a simpler way to filter out Counter keys by length?

I've tried the following it gives the correct output of the filtered Counter but it's iterating though the Counter as a list and then making the list into the Counter again. Is there s a simpler and less computationally expensive way to do the same?

```
from collections import Counter

x = Counter(['a','a', 'ab', 'c', 'hij', 'k'])

threes = Counter([i for i,j in x.items() if len(i) == 3])
twos = Counter([i for i,j in x.items() if len(i) == 2])
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to stick with `Counter` objects specifically?  It seems like you'd be better served by a custom `Counter`-like object that does your specialized counting in a single pass on insert instead of some multi-pass solution that shoehorns what you need in to `Counter`.

Comment: because of some vectorization that will occur later in the pipeline so basic Counter would be easy to manage.

Comment: But a `Counter` just acts like a `dict` for reading.  Still not seeing the need for a `Counter` specifically.

Comment: a counter _is_ a defaultdict, as i understand it, but with some custom methods (which you aren't using?) BTW, i would have expected it to be slightly faster if using a generator (i.e. instead of `Counter([x for x in y])`, just do `Counter(x for x in y)`. I am on python 2.6 so don't have counter and can't run this comparison though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to map key length to key list:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

x = Counter(['a', 'a', 'ab', 'c', 'hij', 'k']) # OR ['a','a','ab','c','hij','k']
by_length = defaultdict(list)
for key in x:
    by_length[len(key)].append(key)

print(by_length[1]) # prints: ['a', 'k', 'c']
print(by_length[2]) # prints: ['ab']
print(by_length[3]) # prints: ['hij']
```

BTW, if what you want is getting list of keys by length, you don't need to create `Counter` object.

Comment: my input is a counter and so it needs to return just a filtered counter =)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the `Counter` documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects). The short answer is that there is not a built-in method for generating a `Counter` containing only items with a certain length.

It would probably more efficient to create the new `Counter` objects separately from the original list:

```
l = ['a','a', 'ab', 'c', 'hij', 'k']
threes = Counter([x for x in l if len(x) == 3])
```